# Search between two dates

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I want to search specific data between two dates.

However the design doesn't look good and the space is limited. I want to hear your ideas.

The red arrow shows the date interval area that I'm talking about.

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: I really Love of your contains, and colors concept is quite good.. i am designing on it to make a dribbble shot.. with overall changes... will post soon...

Comment: @SushantKumarPradhan nice to hear these words. I am looking forward your response. thank you.

Comment: @SushantKumarPradhan any update :) ?

Comment: yes its about to finish updating soon 
sorry for the late update

Comment: Look at some airline flight searches.

Answer (score 1):

The content and the Color selection are quite good. Any way i tried a redesign version of this hope you will like and may be help you for your design 
 i make the things on more visualization and info-graphic. if you have any problem then you can comment..

[image]

And about the Date picking i have an option attached bellow,
This is a concept you can choose a date range and time using a single calendar.

[image]

hope it can help you :)

Comment: wow, thats lovely. I just love it. Thank you. I will rethink every inch of the images :)